# How to stack columns of data-frame and merge columns in r?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data-frame with **these** characteristics:

```
Z Y X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 ... X30 

A n1 1 2 1 2 1 2 1      2

B n2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1      2

C n3 1 2 1 2 1 2 1      2

D n4 1 2 1 2 1 2 1      2

.
.
.
```

My purpose is to stack the column x1, x2, … x30, and associated the new column with columns z, y, and x. Some like this:

```
Newcolumn zyx
1                    x-y-z
```

... I need a data-frame like **this**:

```
  colum1                  colum2  

1 A+n1+X1.headername      1

2 B+n2+X2.headernam       2

3 C+n3X3.headername       1

4 D+n4X4.headername       2

.                         .
.                         .
.                         .
```

I’m trying to build a function, but I have some troubles
I follow this code for the data-frame:

```
df$zy <- paste(df$z,"-",df$y)
```

After that, I eliminate the columns “z” and “y”:

```
df$z <- NULL
df$y <- NULL
```

And save column df$zy as data-frame for use later:

```
df_zy <- as.data.frame(df$zy)
```

Then eliminate df$xy of original dataframe:

```
df$xy <- NULL
```

After that, I save as data-frame the column x1, and incorporate df_zy and name of column x1 (the name is “1”):

```
a <- as.data.frame(df$`1`)
b <- cbind(a, df_xy, x_column= 1)
b$zy <- paste(b$x_column,"-",b$` df$zy`)
b$` df$zy ` <- NULL
b$ x_column <- NULL
colnames(b)
names(b)[names(b) == "b$`1`"] <- "new_column"
```

This works, but only for the column x1 and I need this for x1 to x30, and stack all new column 
Does anybody have an answer to this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, @Eric Morales Mora and welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide more details about your problem and add some tags so we know what you want help for.

Comment: Hi @BossElijah! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi @Eric Morales Mora, no problem! I know it's hard to write good questions on StackOverflow because I've only been here for 4 months. You'll get it! An upvote for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could work for you

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble::tibble(Z = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
               Y = c("n1", "n2", "n3", "n4"),
               X1 = rep(1,4),
               X2 = rep(2,4),
               X3 = rep(1,4),
               X4 = rep(2,4)) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(ID = as.character(dplyr::row_number()),
                column1 = paste0(Z, "+", Y, "+X", ID, ".headername")) %>% 
  tidyr::nest(-c(ID, column1)) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(column2 = purrr::map2_dbl(ID,
                                          data, ~ .y %>% 
                                            dplyr::select(tidyselect::contains(.x)) %>% 
                                            dplyr::pull()))

A tibble: 4 x 4
  ID    column1                      data column2
  <chr> <chr>              <list<df[,6]>>   <dbl>
1 1     A+n1+X1.headername        [1 x 6]       1
2 2     B+n2+X2.headername        [1 x 6]       2
3 3     C+n3+X3.headername        [1 x 6]       1
4 4     D+n4+X4.headername        [1 x 6]       2
```